# Getting ngmodel value out of duplicated forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

Excuse me if this a silly question,but I have tried so much. I have a two form fields which duplicate with **add** button. So here I am trying to access the input from **value** formfield using ngmodel. But when I duplicate the set of formfield using add button. The input which I entered in the **value** form field repeats when I click the add button. This happens when I am using ngmodel to get value. Is there any other way to solve this? Comment down if u have any doubts regarding the question

My sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-forked-t7y9u?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I think you should have to use formArray.

Comment: Can u plsss give an example how? @TitusSutioFanpula

Comment: Why you are using ngModel there is already formControl attached to it. FYI. I am the original creator of that codesandbox which you have forked.

Comment: I cant get those values using formcontrol. Yes and sorry I am giving u full credit for that @VimalPatel

Comment: You are by using "this.myForm.value" please check this. https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-rqdhc

Comment: I am trying to display the value alone in html (to asssign that form value to another variable in html) to asssign it to another variable. I am getting  [object Object] as output @VimalPatel

Comment: Because its a json data, please check the code which I have provided in my codesandbox. If you want to see the actual data use it like this. {{form.value | json}}

Comment: I have checked bro but I am trying to use that formcontrol value to assign it to another variable. Even if I use json I cant pick the value alone. It will be in json format. I want the value alone. I have tried this pls check    https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-forked-rhuyq?file=/src/app/app.component.html            @VimalPatel

Comment: You are doing it wrong how can use a single variable to store array of values.To get the value for 1 field use it like that -> this.myForm.value.map((x) => x.value)

Comment: I used    a:number;          let z = this.myForm.value.map((x) => x.value);     this.a = z;         In html:   <p>aaa:{{a}}</p>
This still didnt work. Sorry if I am doing it wrong again @VimalPatel        https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-forked-rhuyq?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Why you are linking your form to a variable what is the problem if you use the form directly to get the value?

Comment: Even if I do like how u say. I am still not getting the value in html                                       this.a=this.myForm.value.map((x) => x.value);    In html: <p>aaa:{{a}}</p>   Like this right? @VimalPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value from Form and show it in UI. You can create a getter property in component which will return the value from that particular field like this.

```
get values() {
    return this.myForm.value.map(x => x.value);
};
```

Add then bind this variable into your UI like this.

```
<p>result:{{values}}</p>
```

As your form is an formArray you will get your result in an array type.

Comment: Hey in that codesandbox in ur code I am trying to delete set of formfield(I mean after duplicating). In my html button I have used this          (click)="DelBtn(a)"
and in my ts I have used this                         DelBtn = (delIndex) => this.myForm.controls.splice(delIndex, 1);

Comment: If I have three duplicates this code deletes the one that is present first on the top. Is there any way I could delete the latest duplicated one? @Vimal

Comment: create a sandbox and share the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-forked-t7y9u?file=/src/app/app.component.ts    This is the link @Vimal

Comment: Its actually deleting the first  in the array instead of last

Comment: I tried using pop instead of splice it worked. @Vimal

Comment: There are many errors in console in your codesandbox and pop will not work as it will remove the last one not the one user has delete.

Comment: Yeah I checked now bro u are right. And the above solution too is not applicable. get values() {
    return this.myForm.value.map(x => x.value);
};  Here When I get the value from the get values() the first time the value is 1 and next time if I duplicate and get the value the value is 1,2. Can u pls give me a solutiion for that.

Comment: Is there any way to give a specific value of that form field alone instead of all values in that formcontrol?

Comment: Check this out:- https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-rqdhc?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for that bro. But I coultdn't solve the  problem of getting formcontrol values. For each formgroup I have a seperate button called modal through which a popup comes The popup contains input of that formgroups  formfield named value. So if at a time 5 forms are duplicated. There will be 5 modal buttons. All those 5 forms will have formfield name value  which will have respective values. So if I click those respective modal buttons I need the respective inputs of value formfield.

Comment: I tried using slice() to remove the last one if the length of the list is greater than 1 because all those inputs of value formfield forms as a list. But it didnt work because if I click the 5th modal button and if I click the first one the wrong value comes. I feel that it has something to do with the formcontrol and formgroup change. Do u have any idea? @Vimal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153417/how-to-copy-or-duplicate-an-entire-form-without-formcontrolname-issues     Please checkout my question if ur free @Vimal