# Getting unique formcontrol values for duplicated formfields angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

**Introduction**:

I have a **reactiveform**. It contains two form fields named **name** and **value**. So I have a **add** button which duplicates the form. So if I click it the form fields **name** and **value** duplicates. So I am trying to use the respective inputs of the formfield named **value** below. I assign it to (I mean the one in html)**formvalues** below the form field. So when I enter the input(lets say 1) of the **value** formfield  in the first form, the **formvalues** variable below gets updated to that input(1) entered. So now If I duplicate the form and enter another input(lets say 2) in that **value** formfield. Now the **formvalues** gets extra value 1,2.

**Myproblem**:

In real time I have a **popup** button in each set of **reactiveforms**. So In that **popup** the input of the particular **value** formfield appears. So if I duplicate and enter another input in the value formfield and now I click the respective popup of that particular **form** then the input of the respective **value** formfield(duplicated one) should be present. But now what a happens is that all the values present in the respective value formfield appears as (Example: 1,4,6,7).

I dont know whats the real issue here so Forgive me if my question title was misleading. Please comment below if my explanation was unclear.

**SAMPLECODE**: https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-forked-di1js?file=/src/app/app.component.html

**Note**: Most part of the above code link was done by user @VimalPatel here in stackoverflow.I am giving him full credit for the code written in that link

I couldnt install boostrap in that sandbox code, so instead of that I have made a show button instead of popup to show the values I am getting.

Comment: I didn't get your issue. Can you please explain what's wrong in SAMPLECODE you assigned?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I am duplicating formfields. For each set of duplicated formfields I  keep a popup which shows the input of that particular formfield (In this case the input of value formfield). So in my VS code  I tried and Found out that when I click the popup the formcontrol values for all the value formfield gets added like 1,2,3,4 instead of showing the value of that particular formfield like 2 or 4 alone. In my sample code I am trying to get the input of that particular formfield(Eventhough there are multiple value formfields which maybe duplicated by clicking the add button). @yurzui

Comment: In that sample code under the form there is something called as formvalues which gets the values of all formfields from value. I am simply trying to keep a seperate popup button for each set of forms which shows the input of that particular value formfield. But in real time in my vs code I tried this. Instead of showing a particular value from that specific formfield its showing all the values combined seperated by comma(as show in the sample code)1,2,3

Comment: Hope u understood. Pls ask if I am unclear again @yurzui

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried till now. I did not see any code related to above functionality in your codesandbox.

Comment: I couldnt install boostrap in that sandbox code, so instead of that I have made a show button instead of popup to show the values I am getting. Pls adjust @VimalPatel   https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-forked-di1js?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable of type `FormGroup` as your form contains a `FormArray`. It will hold the currently selected form. In your button click pass the current form as argument to your show method.

```
<button (click)="openForm(form)">Show</button>
 
openForm(form: FormGroup) {
     this.selectedFormGroup = form;
}
```

In your template you get show the selected form value like this.

```
<div *ngIf="selectedFormGroup">
    {{selectedFormGroup.value | json}}
</div>
```

Working CodeSandBox

https://codesandbox.io/s/formarraydynamic-rqdhc?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Is there any way to get the value(number) alone of the value formfield?    @Vimal

Comment: you are getting the object just use "this.selectedFormGroup.value.value" to get the value.

Comment: It worked thanks. Grateful for the help. BTW how do u guys instantly come up with a solution whereas I get stuck. I mean I know I am a beginner and u are experienced.But what is the thought proceess behind such strong problem solving skills? @Vimal

Comment: I would strongly advise you to start with javascript basic before diving into Angular or any other framework/library. Get your basic concepts clear otherwise it will be pretty hard journey as a developer.

Comment: Sure will do as u say